# How to install ROS on a Server in a datacenter, and have it connect to Local ROSS severs at my remote site

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Remote Datacenter - Runs Windows Server 2012R2 - Or Potentially some flavor of Linux
Remote machines run ROS on Linux - Rasberry Pi

The only port allowed between  is TCP 443.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254362/hello,-i-would-like-to-install-ros-on-a-server-in-a-datacenter,-and-have-it-connect-to-local-ross-severs-at-my-remote-site-(to-interact-with-hardware-such-as-cameras,-motors,-gps,-etc.---has-anyone-one-done-this/) by [jhutto](https://answers.ros.org/users/29326/jhutto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Robot Web Tools is *probably* your best bet: http://robotwebtools.org

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2017-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0